# SQL Server: severe error when querying a MySQL Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2005, linked-server

Hey, I have been having a problem with my linked servers. I am using Microsoft Server 2003 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2005.

The linked server is a MySQL database. It was defined through SSMS along with all our other databases being controlled through SSMS.

The problem is that for any query that last for more than 5 sec I get this error:

> **[Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the current
>   command. The results, if any, should
>   be discarded.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0 A
>   severe error occurred on the current
>   command. The results, if any, should
>   be discarded.]**

Any other query under 5 sec works fine. I am doing simple `select * from tables`. I have checked all the time-outs etc and have them set at unlimited. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer pertains to the 32-bit limit on queries for ODBC connector.  Here is a link to the bug report:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31413

and the quick answer:

Solution:

1 - On Windows XP just go to Administrative Tools -> Data Source(ODBC) -> Select your
ODBC connection which you have used for Linked Server.

2- Click on "Details" button

3- Click on "Flag 3" Tab

4- Checked the option "Limit Column Size to 32-bit range"

This will limit longtext field to 32-bit range so that your query will work.

that's it. Your query will work now without modifying the schema, as i was not in favor
of modifying existing schema.

Note: Please make sure that you are not loosing data, in my case the actual data was in
range of 32-bit . So it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31413) will help you find a resolution

Comment: You were correct...the answer was in bug report.  Thanks so much.  I will answer it myself for any other people that are reading this question and want a quick answer but I will give you the credit.